# Can't use custom 403

Tags: php, .htaccess, litespeed

I'm using below code in `.htaccess` for showing custom 403 error page on my website.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

Though I'm using `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` for showing 404 page, and that's working correctly, But custom 403 is not working. It shows me this (See the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eTOM.png ) upon opening a restricted directory.

The server is running LiteSpeed. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The sintaxis is good, try:

- Make sure you're really having a 403 error with a var_dump(http_response_code());
- remove this line from .htaccess, if you got the same result it's possible that the error is in other script file.
- change the name of 403.php, if you got the same result it's possible that you have another "ErrorDocument 403" in the .htaccess.
- change the name of 403.php and the "ErrorDocument 403" line too, if you got the same result it's possible that the error is in the 403.php script, you can't empty and put only a "test message" and try again now.